# Deploy Mongodb and NodeJS with Kubernetes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, kubernetes

I am learning *Kubernetes* and finding some suggestions about deploying my application.

My application background:

> Backend: NodeJS
>
> Frontend: ReactJS
>
> Database: MongoDB (Just run **mongod** to start instead of using MongoDB cloud services)

I already know how to use ***Docker compose*** to deploy the application in single node.

And now I want to deploy the application with Kubernetes (3 nodes).

So how to deploy MongoDB and make sure the MongoDB data is **synchronize** in 3 nodes?

I have researched some information about this and I am confused on some keywords.

**E.g. Deploy a Standalone MongoDB Instance,
StatefulSet, ...**

Are this information / articles suitable for my situation? or do you know any information about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can install mongodb using [this](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/mongodb) helm chart.

> You can start the MongoDB chart in replica set mode with the following parameter: replicaSet.enabled=true
>
> Some characteristics of this chart are:
>
> Each of the participants in the replication has a fixed stateful set so you always know where to find the primary, secondary or arbiter nodes.
> The number of secondary and arbiter nodes can be scaled out independently.
> Easy to move an application from using a standalone MongoDB server to use a replica set.

See [here](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/mongodb#configuration-and-installation-details) to learn configuration and installation details

Answer (score 0):

You can create helm charts for your apps for deployment -

- Create Dockerfile for your app, make sure you copy the build that was created using `npm build`
- Push to dockerhub or any other registry like ACR or ECR
- Add the image tags in helm deployments & pass values from values.yaml

For MongoDb deployment, use this chart https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/mongodb